# Is collapsibility a homotopy invariant?

Tags: algebraic-topology

There are some similar characterizations of a simplicial complex, with the implication relations:
$$\textrm{nonevasive}\Rightarrow\textrm{collapsible}\Rightarrow\textrm{contractible}\Rightarrow\textrm{acyclic}\Rightarrow \chi(\Delta)=1$$
while none of these implications are considered invertible.

Amongst these properties, the rightmost three are clearly homotopy invariants. But as for collapsibility or nonevasiveness, I don't know if they can be generalized to topological spaces, and thus I have no idea if they are invariant under homotopy equivalence.

Formally, the question is, if $\Delta_1\simeq\Delta_2$ are two homotopy equivalent simplicial complexes, it is always true that:
$$\Delta_1\textrm{ is collapsible (nonevasive)}\Leftrightarrow\Delta_1\textrm{ is collapsible (nonevasive) ?}$$

Comment: "Considered invertible" is a strange choice of wording. The implications either are invertible or they aren't. It's not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your question.

You say that collapsible⇒contractible is not invertible. Let $\Delta_1$ be a contractible but not collapsible simplicial complex. Let $\Delta_2$ be a collapsible complex.

Then $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are both homotopy equivalent to a point. However $\Delta_2$ is collapsible and $\Delta_1$ is not.

Comment: (You can even take $\Delta_2$ to simply be a point.)